# How to prove $\operatorname{ord}_G(a^k) = r/\gcd(r,k)$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group and $a \in G$ an element with $\operatorname{ord}_G(a) = r$, then $\operatorname{ord}_G(a^k) = r/\gcd(r,k)$. I know that this statement is correct, but how can one prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $gcd(r,k)=d$ and $ord(a^k)=m$, it is trivial that $(a^k)^\frac{r}{d}=e\Rightarrow \color{red}{m|\frac{r}{d}}$

since $a^{km}=e \Rightarrow r|km\Rightarrow \frac{r}{d}|m\frac{k}{d}$ but $gcd(\frac{r}{d},\frac{k}{d})=1$ thus by Euclid's lemma $\color{red}{\frac{r}{d}|m}$ so

$\frac{r}{d}=m$

**Theorem**: If $ord(a)=n$ and for $l\in\mathbb{N}, a^l=e$ then $n|l$

Answer (score 2):

First show/recall that $a^n = 1_G$ if *and only if* $r\mid n$.

Then, note that $\operatorname{lcm}(k,r) = kr/\gcd(r,k)$, that is $r/\gcd(k,r)$ is the smallest positive number $t$ such that $kt$ is a multiple of $r$.